# SQLite is not deleting rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in my database, that is created this way:

```
private static String crea_Fichas="CREATE TABLE fichas ("+
        "provincia VARCHAR (40), "+
        "municipio VARCHAR (40), "+
        "distrito VARCHAR (40), "+
        "codficha INTEGER, "+
        "codagente INTEGER, "+
        "domitri VARCHAR(80), "+
        "domfiscal VARCHAR(80), "+
        "CIERNC VARCHAR(13), "+
        "nombrecompleto VARCHAR (255), "+
        "telf1 VARCHAR(12), "+
        "telf2 VARCHAR(12), "+
        "fax VARCHAR(12), "+
        "razonsocial VARCHAR(255), "+
        "nombrecomercial VARCHAR(255), "+
        "email VARCHAR(50), "+
        "codexpediente INTEGER, "+
        "croquis BYTEA, "+
        "codtipoactividad INTEGER, "+
        "primary key(codficha), "+
        "foreign key (codtipoactividad) references tiposactividades(codtipoactividad), " +
        "foreign key (codexpediente) references expedientes (codexpediente), "+
        "foreign key (codagente) references agentes(codagente));";
```

Later in my program, I want to do this:

```
private void deleteExpediente(long codficha) {

    Cursor cursorBorra=db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM fichas where codficha='"+codficha+"'", null);
    dbHelper.copiarDb();

}
```

but, this way, none row is affected. I have checked that codficha exists, database is not null, etc. No Exception is thrown, simply...row is not deleted. copiarDb() is a method to copy my database to another location in my device (is not rooted, so I cannot see the database) and is there where I check the row has not been deleted.

Any idea why I cannot delete that row? Thank you.

Comment: try `db.delete("fichas", "codficha= ? ",new String[] { String.valueOf(codficha));`

Comment: You had a missing } after the first parentheses ;). Trying it now.

Comment: It works with that method, thank you. Do you know why can't I do it using rawQuery?

Comment: `rawQuery(..)` always returns a `data(Cursor)`

Comment: So, a delete operation doesn't returns a cursor with number of rows affected? or some info about the deletion?

Comment: exactly yup. also check the official docs. it's return the total row deleted count.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.delete("fitcas", "codficha = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(codficha) });
```

A rawQuery returns a Cursor of a result set, which is just a reference to the query results. You should just be using a straight delete() call. Take a look at the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

or an SQLiteStatement:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html

Comment: I had it before without the ' , added it to try if that was why it wasn't deleting, tried again now without it, and no luck. Thank you, anyway...

Comment: Yes, as I say in my answer to his comment, it works. But I don't know why i cannot do it using rawQuery

Comment: I used a cursor to keep track of the result of the query. I imagined that it would return the number of rows affected, or something like that.